# ExternalInterface.call not working

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, externalinterface

I am attempting to `ExternalInterface.call()` from inside my SWF.

*Note the call comes from inside a SWF I have embedded into another SWF (the `_root` SWF I have no control over).*

Here is my JavaScript:

```
function player_DoFSCommand(command, args) 
{
    args = String(args);
    command = String(command);

    var arrArgs = args.split(g_strDelim);

    switch (command)
    {
        case "CC_ClosePlayer":

            console.log("yo");
            break;

        default:
            // alert(command);
            break;
    }
}
```

Here is my AS2 code:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

var quiz = _root;

quiz.g_mcFrame.mcFinish.swapDepths(quiz.getNextHighestDepth());
quiz.g_mcFrame.mcFinish._visible = false;
quiz.oSlide.m_oInteraction.m_oVariableMgr.m_arrBoolResumeData = false;

var arrVars:Object = quiz.oSlide.m_oActionHandler.m_oFrame.m_oVariableMgr.m_arrVariables;
var args:Array = [
    arrVars[2].m_nNumber, // Points awarded
    arrVars[3].m_nNumber, // Max points
    arrVars[5].m_nNumber, // Pass percentage
    arrVars[6].m_nNumber, // Pass points
    arrVars[7].m_nNumber, // Score percent
    arrVars[10].m_strString // Result
];

ExternalInterface.call('player_DoFSCommand("CC_ClosePlayer", args)');
ExternalInterface.call('console.log("hello")');
```

The problem is `ExternalInterface.call('player_DoFSCommand("CC_ClosePlayer", args)')` doesn't work, or atleast "yo" doesn't appear in the console as expected.

The script is definitely loaded by the time the ExternalInterface is called. The second call works and "hello" appears in the console, however the first function doesn't fire.

I can verify the function works by typing directly into the console `player_DoFSCommand("CC_ClosePlayer", args)` and it logs successfully.

Comment: add `console.log("called");` before `args = String(args);` What will happen? Or try ExternalInterface.call('player_DoFSCommand("CC_ClosePlayer", "test")');

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you verify that allowScriptAccess is set to true in the embed code?

Try this:

```
 var isAvailable:Boolean = ExternalInterface.available;
 trace(isAvailable);
```

You also want to use ExternalInterface like this, with your arguments passed as the second variable:

```
 ExternalInterface.call("player_DoFSCommand",args);
```

or

```
 ExternalInterface.call("console.log","testing...");
```

Comment: I assumed `allowScriptAccess` was set to true because the parent SWF calls JavaScript functions... however it was using the outdated `swLiveConnect`. I also used your function syntax - followed a bad tutorial on `ExternalInterface`